# how to pass the multiple parameters to the system.threading.timer()

Tags: c#, .net

How can I pass multiple parameters to the callback expected by `System.Threading.Timer()` in C#?

```
timer1[timer] = new System.Threading.Timer(databaseTrensfer, row, dueTime, interval);

public void databaseTrensfer(object row,object unitID)
{
   // do work here
}
```

How can I pass the second parameter to my `databaseTrensfer` function?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would make a new class or struct, having the properties as the `row` and the `unitID`.

Answer (score 6):

The timer callback is defined to take a single parameter:

```
public delegate void TimerCallback(object state);
```

If you need to pass several arguments to your callback, which are known when you register the callback on the `Timer` constructor, then you could use a lambda:

```
Timer CreateTimer(object unitID)
{
    object   row      = ...
    TimeSpan dueTime  = ...
    TimeSpan interval = ...

    return new Timer(x => DatabaseTransfer (x, unitID), row, dueTime, interval);
}

static void DatabaseTransfer(object row, object unitID)
{
    ....
}
```

Writing `x => DataTransfer (x, unitID)` captures the state of your `unitID` variable and is roughly equivalent to this:

```
Timer CreateTimer(object unitID)
{
    object   row      = ...
    TimeSpan dueTime  = ...
    TimeSpan interval = ...

    $Temp temp = new $Temp (unitID);

    return new Timer(temp.Callback, row, dueTime, interval);
}

class $Temp
{
    public $Temp(object arg)
    {
        this.arg = arg;
    }
    public void Callback(object x)
    {
        DataTransfer (x, this.arg);
    }
    private object arg;
}
```

The compiler takes care of constructing the class and plumbing behind the scenes. See for instance an [explanation about closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759837/what-is-so-special-about-closures).

Answer (score 3):

Why not create a class that has properties consisting of the additional items you want to pass in? Then just pass the actual container class.

Comment: number of threads are shared this function instance with individual row how to provide the unique data to each thread

Comment: @vrushali, From what I understand so far of your situation this approach should be fine. With you "container" class you can pass all the elements you need to work within a specific context.