# C# timer - schedule a call to a function accepting an argument

Tags: c#, delegates, timer

I want to call a function every X seconds. I read on SO about the the System.Threading.Timer and so I do:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(TimeCallBack), null, 0, 50000);
```

which calls the function:

```
void TimeCallBack();
```

However, I'd like to pass an argument to that function so that the timer calls the following function:

```
void TimeCallBack(MyClass mc);
```

I could make the instance I'm passing global but I'd rather pass it. From what I see the TimerCallback delegate is used in the Timer constructor. Any way I can use my own delegate/function call?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381878/how-to-pass-the-multiple-parameters-to-the-system-threading-timer) previous question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass an argument to the callback through the `state` parameter of the [Timer Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x96zfy7.aspx):

```
Timer timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(TimeCallBack), mc, 0, 50000);
```

*Callback:*

```
void TimeCallBack(object state)
{
    MyClass mc = (MyClass)state;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I was wondering what the userState parameter was for. Thanks!